# Having irrelevant extra parameters and DTO to impelememt IRepository in Domain layer

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, repository-pattern, onion-architecture, irepository

I have a solution that I have implemented by Onion architecture and DDD like [eShopOnContainers](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/tree/dev/src/Services/Ordering).

But I have an issue to do this, so I decided share it with you. I try to explain it by an example. You suppose I have a `interface` that named `IOrderRepository` like [IOrderRepository](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/blob/dev/src/Services/Ordering/Ordering.Domain/AggregatesModel/OrderAggregate/IOrderRepository.cs)

```
public interface IOrderRepository : IRepository<Order>
    {
        Order Add(Order order);               // first issue
        Task<OrderDTO> GetAsync(int orderId); // second issue
    }
```

**First issue**

I implemented `Add` method like [OrderRepository](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/blob/dev/src/Services/Ordering/Ordering.Infrastructure/Repositories/OrderRepository.cs) but I need extra parameters in `Add` method like following code:

```
public Order Add(Order order, int par1, int par2)
    {
        // I need a DTO to persist order  
        OrderDTO orderDTO = new OrderDTO({Order = order, Par1 = par1, Par2 = par2 });

        // Call a method with orderDTO parameter as a service to insert order             
    }
```

As you can see, implementing `IOrderRepository` is wrong because of extra parameters that I need.

**Wrong solutions for first issue**

I have two wrong solutions to tackle with this issue.

**1- Adjusting `IOrderRepository`**

Changing input `IOrderRepository`parameters by adding the parameters like this:

```
public interface IOrderRepository : IRepository<Order>
    {
        Order Add(Order order, int par1, int par2);           
    }
```

As I know, there isn't any business rule for `par1 and par2` and to do implement DDD, first of all I should specify `IRepository`, but by using this solution, I put Infrastructure layer concerns in Domain layer that is wrong architecture.

**2- Take `IOrderRepository` to Infrastructure layer**

I can put `IOrderRepository` in Infrastructure layer, but it's another wrong architecture because as far as I know this sort of interfaces should be located in `Domain layer`.

**My first question**

> 1- How I can use extra parameters in methods of a Repository in Infrastructure layer to implement IRepository of Domain layer that there
>   isn't any connection between the parameters and Domain layer?

**Second issue**

As you can see in `IOrderRepository`, I should implement `GetAsync` method that returns `OrderDTO` including `Order` and extra parameters. As I know, I can't use DTO (Data Transfer Object) in Domain layer. I couldn't come up with an idea to handle it.

**My second question**

> 2- How I can return DTO `OrderRepository` methods that is in
>   infrastructure layer, but I can't apply it in `IOrderRepository` that
>   is in Domain layer.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Extension methods are your friends here

Comment: Also your mixing of types here is only going to cause more confusion.

Comment: You have not explained why `OrderDTO`  was introduced

Comment: @Nkosi I thought on static methods like extensions, but I use it, how I can connect Domain layer and infrastructure? Also, I could get your mean about making confusion.

Comment: @Nkosi I should call a service to get `Order` that returns `OrderDTO`.

Comment: You may need to better explain what it is you are trying to do. The current example is very broad and a bit unclear. Try to narrow the scope of the problem.

Comment: @AliSoltani can you explain why you need these field multiple people have asked that question, yet you seem to avoid it each time.

Comment: @AliSoltani Why are you Constructing a DTO in your add method? This really smells like an X,Y Problem, I would guess that you don't actually need these field in the repository

Comment: @johnny5 Actually I should call stored procedures like `AddOrder` and `GetOrder` to insert `Order` and get my info that I should use it in UI. In `AddOrder`, I need to extra parameters that I mentioned and by calling `GetOrder` I get `OrderDTO`.

Comment: @AliSoltani No you should not called stored procedures.  1. You aren't even implementing your interface properly.  2. your not following the pattern properly. 
See my answer it is complex but its a start, to properly handling DDD

Comment: I don't understand, do you need to pass `int par1, int par2` to save Order in the `OrderRepository` or not?

Answer (score 4):

Since we have no context as to why you need those two parameters you could also go with two other, probably less intrusive, options:-

Firtly, you could have a new class that inherits from `Order` and also contains those extra parameters:

```
public class MyOrder : Order
{ 
    int Par1 { get; set; }
    int Par2 { get; set; }
}
```

In your repository you could then cast, or safe-cast, to the `MyOrder` class.

Another option would be to use an extension method for `IOrderRepository`:

```
public static class SomeExtension
{
    public static void MySave(this IOrderRepository repository, int par1, int par2)
    {
        // do things
    }
}
```

Perhaps these would not work in your scenario so YMMV.  In either case you may need to take another look at your design.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your first suggestion is similar to apply a DTO that I can't do it because of using DDD. The second one is impossible to me because as I mentioned, in order to implement DDD and Onion architecture, I should exactly  implement `IOrderRepository` and using static method isn't proper solution to me.

Comment: Since we have no context it may be that those extra parameters are not domain-related.  If they *are* then you need to have another look at your design.  If, however, they are orthogonal (such as security, connections, logging) then you may get away with some other behind the scenes mechanism that is injected into your repository that can provide the values.

Comment: In my view, your answer is wrong, because firstly I can't define a new class like `MyOrder` in Domain layer. Also, I need to implement `IOrderRepository` that I define it in Domain layer, static method in this case is useless.

Comment: Perhaps you could have an application service that performs the extra functionality that you would've done with those extra parameters.  The service could call the repository and after that you perform whatever you need.  In this way you don't have to pass those parameters to the repository.  Again, without the proper context it is difficult to assist you with a solution.

Comment: You are right. I could do everything that I need in Application layer, combining data to create `OrderDTO` for instance, but my problem is `OrderRepository` that I should call a stored procedure to insert data as well as get it. For calling sp, I need extra parameters and also the return object from get sp is `OrderDTO`. In DDD, I need to implement `IOrderRepository` that know nothing about extra parameters and DTOs. So far I couldn't find a solution to this problem.

Comment: What do those parameters represent?  Are they infrastructure such as dates or a username?  Are they common across all your SPs?

Comment: The parameters in real projects could be different type, but usually they includes dates and usernames. But they aren't common in whole of my SPs. In fact, sometime I should call SPs that return objects that aren't same with my Entities.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an X-Y Problem, There are serveral issues with your code and you are not explaining the problem well enough, your just explaining what you want as an answer.

If you look at the Code you've linked to this is their implementation of IRepository (I've omitted irrelevant methods to answer the question)

```
public interface IOrderRepository : IRepository<Order>
{
    Order Add(Order order); 
    Task<Order> GetAsync(int orderId);
}
```

Here you can see that they cleared are only Operating on the Order and not the DTO Yet in the implementation you've provided you return the DTO, which would be impossible to return without link a separate parameter

```
public interface IOrderRepository : IRepository<Order>
{
    Order Add(Order order);               
    Task<OrderDTO> GetAsync(int orderId); 
}
```

You probably want a more complex architecture but there won't be enough space to layout the full code so I'll just give you a Gyst 
Take in both Parameters Order and OrderDTO, and add infrastructure for handling adaptations

```
public interface IOrderRepository : IRepository<OrderDTO>
{
    OrderDTO Add(OrderDTO order); 
    Task<OrderDTO> GetAsync(int orderId);
}


public interface IAdaptable<TEntity, TDTO>
{
    TDTO ToDTO(TEntity entity);
    TEntity ToEntity(TDTO entityDTO, TEntity entity);
}
```

Then you'll need a base class for handling the operations

```
public class BaseRepository<TEntity, TDTO> : IRepository<TEntity, TDTO>
    where TEntity : class, new()
{
     protected DbContext _context;
     protected IAdaptable<TEntity, TDTO> _adapter;
     public BaseRepository(DbContext context, IAdaptable<TEntity, TDTO> adapter)
     {
         this._context = context;
         this._adapter = adapter;
     }

     public TDTO Add(TDTO dto)
     {
        var entity = this._adapter.ToEntity(dto, new TEntity());
        this._context.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
        this._context.SaveChanges();

         return this._adapter.ToDTO(entity);
     }
}
```

Now your base repository handles most of your base logic all you have to do is implement the adapter, e.g Automapper is a nice way to go.

```
public class OrderAdapter : IAdaptable<Order, OrderDTO>
{
    IOtherDependentService _service;
    public OrderAdapter(IOtherDependentService service)
    {
        this._service = service;
    }

    OrderDTO ToDTO(Order order)
    {
       var orderPars = this._service.GetParsFromOrder(order.Id);
       var dto = new OrderDTO{
           Order = order, 
           Pars1 = orderPars.Pars1, 
           Pars2 = orderPars.Pars2
       };

       return dto;

    }

    //.... Implement the rest of the interface you get the picture
}
```

You should be able to get the Gyst from this

Comment: Thanks for your time to answer my question,first of all, your code includes `IRepository<OrderDTO>` that's impossible because of location of `IRepository` that is in Domain layer. So we should use it just for Domain Entities. Finally, in my view, my problem is clear enough, I need more parameters to class `AddOrder` and the return value from `GetOrder` sp is `OrderDTO`, however in `IOrderRepository` know nothing about these things. How I can implement Domain Layer and Repository properly.

Comment: @AliSoltani, you are the one who introduced these issues in your question you are creating a dto in the add method.  No your not being clear, you are just saying you need these parameters but you're not explaining why you need them.  If they aren't relevant to creating an order you dont need them if they are relavant to creating an order  then they should be in the order.  If they are dro properties then you need to change the architecture to use something similar to mine.

Comment: Ali explain clearly why you need them instead of just saying that you do.  Show us in the code it's clear that your architecture is the issue but you're trying to have us make your solution instead of making the right solution

Answer (score 0):

What is in the parameters?

If it's part of the Order, your model should reflect that.  Having to take in supposedly unrelated information is usually a very clear sign that your object model doesn't reflect reality.  Which is the whole point of DDD.

If they're other things that will be consistent across the life of the repository, give them as parameters to the Repository on its construction (dependency injection).  It can then use these internally to store the item.

Here's an example of the latter - let's say I have an eCommerce company, and we have a legacy order system that needs to be notified on older orders, but in new orders it's no longer needed.  I can encapsulate this behavior in my factory like (C# example):

```
public class OrderRepository : IOrderRepository
{
     private LegacyOrderService _legacyService;
     public OrderRepository(LegacyOrderService legacyService){
          _legacyService = legacyService;
     }

     public Order Add(Order order){
         if(!order.isNewOrder){
              _legacyService.notify(order.id);
         }

         # do the rest
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. First of all I updated my question to cover all of my issues. Please see it again. Secondly, I figure out an solution to tackle with my first issue like you by injecting an `ExtraParametersProviderService` to get extra parameters in infrastructure, but I have encountered with implementing `Get` method.

Comment: The question of it these parameters are infrastructure or domain info remains though.  If they're the former, they don't belong in your domain model, and likely not in your repo.